# IBM MQ with C# How to change the message header to MQHRF

Tags: c#, websphere, ibm-mq

In C# how can I change the message header to MQHRF instead of MQHRF2?

Thank you.

I tried with:

`message.SetStringProperty();`

Comment: The real question is why would you want to?  MQHRF was a header I believe only used for legacy queue based pub/sub which was superseded by integrated pub/sub at MQ v7.0, this uses MQHRF2 and it is also the standard for IBM MQ JMS based messages.

Comment: Because, the IBM MQ that I need to send the message uses MQHRF.

Comment: Does it involve pub/sub?

Answer (score 0):

It is very, very odd to want to use MQRFH.  This embedded message format was pretty much dropped 10 years ago.

There is no MQRFH class in MQ.NET, so you will need to create your own code for it.  Go look up MQRFH structure in the ***cmqc.h*** file.

The MQRFH structure layout is:

```
{MQRFH structure} {name value string} {message data}
```

Here's a picture of a MQRFH message:

[image]

Note: Be careful with the "Name Value String".  It must end on a 4-byte boundary - meaning that you need to pad it with blanks (if necessary) and the "StrucLength" field in the MQRFH structure must include the length of the "Name Value String".

Comment: But I need a sample how to do this in c#

Comment: Create a class based on the MQRFH structure in the cmqc.h file.